# saving the last reading position

Tags: javascript

I need to get and save the reading position of the posts in wordpress website for the user to continue reading from the same position, when he/she signs in again, I tried with scrolltop in jquery but it is not cross browser compatible and gives different values in internet explorer, chrome and firefox, Is there any other way out

Answer (score 1):

I believe `offsetTop` will help you. Since it is screen size independent.

See the link below :

[Find position with JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)